# How to prevent loading a Vimeo video player iFrame twice

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, flexbox, vimeo-api

I'm displaying an Vimeo video iFrame in a flexbox container. I'm setting the size of the iFrame with JS. The issue is that the page loads twice, first I guess with standard settings then with the ones I set with JS.

How can I prevent the double loading?

I give you a JSFiddle because the effect is not seen in a StackSnippet due to cookie sandboxing

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zinyosrim/tb8hrjau/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="dc-video-row">
  <div class="dc-video-content">
    <iframe 
            src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/436703027' 
            frameborder='0' 
            webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>         
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="dc-text-content">
    text
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.dc-video-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.dc-text-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.dc-text-content > * {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.dc-text-content > p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
```

JS

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
const player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

Promise.all([player.getVideoWidth(), player.getVideoHeight()]).then(function(dimensions) {

  let aspectRatio = dimensions[1]/dimensions[0];
  
  const videoBox = document.querySelector(".dc-video-content");
  const newVideoWidth = document.querySelector(".dc-video-row").offsetWidth/3
  videoBox.style.width =  newVideoWidth + "px";
  videoBox.style.height = newVideoWidth * aspectRatio + "px";

  iframe.width = newVideoWidth
  iframe.height = newVideoWidth * aspectRatio;
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan You moved the code to a code snippet. I initially decided not to use the SO built-in snippet editor because the code didn't run there, but it did in jsfiddle

Comment: my code doesn't run in snippet, possibly because of the vimeo player. The effect I have in jsfiddle doesn't show up in the snippet

Comment: Ah, It's due to the cookie sandbox.

Comment: And the answer is yes, it loads more than once since the player detects the size change and fist loads `?mw=200&mh=300&q=70` and then `mw=500&mh=749&q=70`